# Using format with multiple objects

Tags: python

This is a code from a LinkedIn post, there is one line starting at comments.append that is not shown fully (I put ???). I was wondering if anyone know how to solve it.

```
price = data["Adj Close"].loc["2020-03-02":"2020-12-21"]
fig.ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,5))
comments = []
for ticker in tickers:
    returns = price.apply(lambda x:np.log(x / x.shift(1))).dropna()
    title="{} . cumulative log return".format(ticker)
    ax.plot(returns.index,returns[ticker].cumsum(), label=ticker)
    final_cum_log_return = returns[ticker].cumsum().iloc[-1]
    exp_final_cum_log_return = (np.exp(final_cum_log_return)-1)*100
    comments.append("{2}: Cum log return = {0}.\nSimple return = (exp({0}) -1)*100= {1} %.\n".format(final_cum_log_return ???))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
print("On Dec. 21:\n")
[print(x) for x in comments]
```

The only way I know how to change it fixes most of the problem, but my code shows the following error "No handles with labels found to put in legend". And the result is not as clean as the one in the LinkedIn post.

```
    comments.append("{tickers}: Cum log return = {returns}.\nSimple return = (exp({returns}) -1)*100= {exp_final_cum_log_return} %.\n".format(tickers=tickers,returns=returns,exp_final_cum_log_return=exp_final_cum_log_return))
```

[The author's result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGNkm.png)

[My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3joKT.png)

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/stock-price-analysis-python-anthony-skolozdrzyk-ardouin/

Answer (score 0):

Not really that hard.  #0 is the final cum log, #1 is the exp final cum log, #2 is the ticker symbol.

```
    comments.append("{2}: Cum log return = {0}.\nSimple return = (exp({0}) -1)*100= {1} %.\n".format(final_cum_log_return, exp_final_cum_log_return, ticker))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!